# Add item in recursive list without refreshing

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have a recursive list and I can add items at many levels of this list.

When I refresh the list, I would like to concat the new item in the right place.

The expected result:

```
object1
   object1.1
   object1.2 //new
object2
```

The current result:

```
  object1
       object1.1     
  object2
  object1.2 //new
```

HTML

```
     <ul>
      <ng-container
        *ngTemplateOutlet="recursiveListTmpl; context: { list: list$ | async}">
      </ng-container>
    </ul>

<ng-template #recursiveListTmpl let-list="list">
      <li
        *ngFor="let item of list; let i = index; trackBy: byId"
        class="ui-select-toggle mb-1"
        [class.active]="item.toggle">
        <span> {{ item.code }} - {{ item.name }} </span>

        <ul>
          <div *ngIf="item.toggle">
            <li
              *ngFor="let item2 of item.subList"
              class="ui-select-toggle mb-1"
              [class.active]="item2.toggle"
              [ngValue]="item2" >
              <span> {{ item2.code }} - {{ item2.name}} </span>
...
</ng-template>
```

TS

```
  list$ = new BehaviorSubject([]);

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getlist();
  }


  byId(index, item) {
    return item.id;
 }

  getlist() {
    this.service.storedList.subscribe(d => this.list$.next(d));    
  }
  //call when a new item in the parent list is added
  refreshList(d){
    this.list$.next(this.list$.value.concat(d))
}

 refreshList2(d) {
    this.list$.value
      .map((x) => x.subList.filter((x) => x.parent_id == d.parent_id))
      .forEach((e) => {
        if (e.length != 0) {
          console.log(e.concat(d));
          e.concat(d);
        }
      });
  }
```

When I trigger the second function, the console displays what I want but the new item isn't added to the recursive list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this, I make a new `BehaviorSubject` then concat the param to the subList and suscribe

```
  refreshList2(d) {
    var subject = new BehaviorSubject([]);
      var parent = this.list$.value.find((x) => x.id == d.parentObject_id);
        subject.next(parent.subList.concat(d));
        subject.subscribe((data) => {
          this.list$.subscribe(() => (parent .subList = data));
        });
  }
```